# Can I apply for a patent and a trademark in the same application?

Tags: trademark

When filing a USPTO patent application for a device & process, is the trademark name associated with the device & process filed separately or within the patent application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separately.

Patents and trademarks are entirely unrelated kinds of intellectual property. Indeed, in some cases, they are handled by different agencies (such as in Europe, with the EPO for patents and the EUIPO for trademarks).